# Trimming whitespace from char-type columns using MyBatis

Tags: mybatis

Is there an easy way of trimming whitespace off of char-type columns when using a MyBatis XML mapper resultMap or resultType? Or do I need to write a custom type handler/add code to my JavaBean setters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a type handler that will be used instead of the default `StringTypeHandler`. It would be handier if there was a flag on the XML, though.

Answer (score 1):

This a simple example for removing whitespace from VARCHAR column following [TypeHandlers – MyBatis 3](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#typeHandlers).

```java
package com.foo.bar.mybatis.handler;

import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import org.apache.ibatis.type.BaseTypeHandler;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.JdbcType;
import org.apache.ibatis.type.MappedJdbcTypes;

@MappedJdbcTypes(JdbcType.VARCHAR)
public class StringTrimTypeHandler extends BaseTypeHandler<String>  {

    @Override
    public String getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("StringSpaceTypeHandler.getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, String columnName) [rs=" + rs + ", columnName=" + columnName + "]");
        return rs.getString(columnName);
    }

    @Override
    public String getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("StringSpaceTypeHandler.getNullableResult(ResultSet rs, int columnIndex) [rs=" + rs + ", columnIndex=" + columnIndex + "]");
        return rs.getString(columnIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public String getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("StringSpaceTypeHandler.getNullableResult(CallableStatement cs, int columnIndex) [cs=" + cs + ", columnIndex=" + columnIndex + "]");
        return cs.getString(columnIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public void setNonNullParameter(PreparedStatement ps, int i, String parameter, JdbcType jdbcType) throws SQLException {
        System.out.println("StringSpaceTypeHandler.setNonNullParameter() [ps=" + ps + ", i=" + i + ", parameter=" + parameter + ", jdbcType=" + jdbcType + "]");
        parameter = parameter.trim();
        ps.setString(i, parameter);
    }

}
```

The key part is using [trim()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) in `setNonNullParameter()` method to remove heading and tailing whitespace before pass it to `PreparedStatement`.

After creating `StringTrimTypeHandler` class, you need to config it in `mybatis-config.xml`.

```xml
<!-- mybatis-config.xml -->

<configuration>
.....
    <typeHandlers>
        <typeHandler handler="com.foo.bar.mybatis.handler.StringTrimTypeHandler"/>
    </typeHandlers>
.....
</configuration>
```

You then could config [logging – MyBatis 3](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/logging.html) in MyBatis to see the actual the sql parameter.